# Can '@media query break-inside: avoid' and 'display: grid' work together?

Tags: html, css, printing, media-queries

I have generated html and css that users will be printing. Each `<div class="entry">...</div>` should effectively be an index card with content. I added these rules to the `<body>`

```
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(auto-fill, 120px);
  grid-row-gap: 0.5em;
  grid-column-gap: 1em;
```

and the layout looks reasonable except that when printing it will break some of the cards accross pages so I added

```
@media print {
  .entry {
      break-inside: avoid;
  }
}
```

This does not work, the print preview still shows the page breaks coming in the middle of the entry divs.
If I remove the grid css then the `break-inside: avoid` is honored.

Is there any reasonable way to get these two features to work together?

Edit: At Brett's request here is a jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/3sxt192h/ with the minimal repro content
If you take that html and css and remove both `display:grid` and `break-inside` the print preview shows it breaking inside a div. Adding the `break-inside` works and it doesn't break mid-div. Add `display:grid` and you can see that it breaks mid-div again.

Comment: Please edit your question to add a working snippet. This will contain both your HTML and CSS and allow us to help you efficiently.

Comment: I suppose I can do that. I didn't initially because the snippet will have to be quite large in order to reach the page limit and you have to print to see that the break-inside isn't working.

Comment: @BrettDonald I added some repro content in a jsfiddle along with some more instructions.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same results as you when I tried it.

You could use CSS columns instead of a grid, which seems to work fine in Chrome, but not in Safari. Here is the code I used. I tried it as a snippet, but that changes the printing behaviour :-(

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {
  columns: 2;
  gap: 1em;
  margin: 1em;
}
p {
  break-inside: avoid;
  padding: 1em;
  border: 2px solid black;
  background: cyan;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin egestas dui eget eros consectetur, vel lacinia erat tempor. Nunc volutpat, ante quis condimentum faucibus, mi augue posuere libero, luctus luctus leo lacus et ex. Donec non vehicula augue. Mauris a imperdiet est, eu mollis risus. Cras ac libero ac nunc posuere porttitor. Phasellus congue magna quis magna blandit, at feugiat lorem consequat. Aliquam est magna, malesuada non enim ut, vehicula accumsan odio. Donec aliquet, ante at vulputate vehicula, mi justo venenatis turpis, pretium laoreet neque augue quis lacus. Maecenas finibus sed velit vel laoreet. Nunc porttitor sit amet turpis vel efficitur.</p>
<p>Duis mollis volutpat enim, non dignissim libero tincidunt at. Nam mauris nunc, fermentum non suscipit quis, ultricies ac augue. Suspendisse bibendum, massa vel tempus tristique, purus dui tristique ligula, et venenatis sem tortor nec nibh. Aliquam eget justo nec ipsum tincidunt congue non quis velit. Morbi fringilla, erat ut gravida eleifend, mauris urna posuere mauris, id porta turpis felis at nisl. Quisque et mi ac urna viverra efficitur eu sed turpis. Phasellus eget pulvinar lectus. In ac felis id sapien gravida convallis in at lorem.</p>
<p>Donec tincidunt ac tortor sit amet sodales. Nam convallis enim sem, id consectetur nisl ultricies sit amet. Aenean maximus, purus commodo luctus pharetra, lectus lectus lobortis eros, at tristique mi velit vel elit. Pellentesque sed justo non tellus blandit elementum. Phasellus arcu ipsum, posuere id venenatis a, faucibus ut nulla. Sed scelerisque sapien a augue efficitur, ac lobortis nulla sollicitudin. Pellentesque vitae neque vitae turpis aliquet tincidunt. Morbi at ex magna. Vestibulum ornare lacinia rutrum. Curabitur luctus, magna eget consequat rhoncus, purus nunc egestas nulla, at sollicitudin dui lacus et massa. Duis sit amet risus sit amet turpis dignissim lacinia. Suspendisse sagittis cursus dui ut rhoncus. Integer eu ex leo. In sit amet nisi mi. Curabitur nec mollis tortor.</p>
<p>Suspendisse potenti. Sed a hendrerit diam. Praesent tincidunt ut sapien sed porttitor. Fusce consectetur volutpat faucibus. Mauris iaculis efficitur risus, at tempus odio tincidunt at. Praesent volutpat nibh ac elit gravida tempor. Integer laoreet ac nisl ut pretium. Suspendisse et magna ut risus congue tincidunt.</p>
<p>Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Sed non diam viverra, vestibulum magna et, varius dui. In vitae eros efficitur, scelerisque est vitae, fermentum ipsum. Duis imperdiet in orci ut porttitor. In ultrices sollicitudin elementum. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Phasellus elementum magna ornare, tincidunt elit ac, aliquam elit. Suspendisse dictum fermentum massa, a vehicula nisi finibus nec. In mattis tincidunt tellus, ac consequat leo aliquet at. Phasellus ultricies, lorem sed placerat porttitor, urna augue hendrerit mauris, at accumsan tortor justo eu felis. Cras id lacus aliquam, malesuada erat nec, malesuada libero.</p>
<p>Curabitur at ipsum vitae lacus fermentum tincidunt. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Maecenas eu lorem sit amet augue pellentesque pharetra. Praesent semper libero nec efficitur tincidunt. Suspendisse faucibus ultricies porttitor. Duis luctus ut neque tristique condimentum. Aenean ut massa id felis pretium rutrum.</p>
<p>Aenean ultrices, urna a facilisis luctus, diam quam efficitur eros, a posuere leo metus ultrices est. Morbi venenatis dolor ut justo finibus, in semper nisl auctor. Aenean risus ex, viverra vitae neque nec, eleifend laoreet sem. Nam suscipit magna non lectus imperdiet, sit amet venenatis enim molestie. Vestibulum id felis vel dolor hendrerit fringilla nec venenatis odio. Donec dapibus, nunc non pellentesque efficitur, ipsum tortor condimentum tortor, sed laoreet diam ante nec urna. Sed leo massa, eleifend sit amet iaculis at, placerat at elit. Nullam at mollis purus. Quisque faucibus enim hendrerit lacus volutpat, eu dignissim dui venenatis. Nulla accumsan turpis vitae lobortis tincidunt. Morbi maximus arcu sapien, eu tincidunt justo vestibulum eu. Suspendisse luctus tellus dolor, a ornare leo imperdiet sed.</p>
<p>Pellentesque maximus, urna in posuere faucibus, enim sem molestie ante, vel mollis tellus massa vitae odio. Sed elementum at turpis sit amet semper. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Praesent risus ex, commodo sodales iaculis vitae, cursus sit amet nulla. Proin venenatis neque felis, id vulputate arcu cursus et. Quisque venenatis tellus id nisl convallis, id mollis massa condimentum. Vestibulum aliquet tristique lacus vitae viverra. Integer tincidunt eu diam a molestie. Curabitur eleifend urna sit amet aliquet sodales. Suspendisse et felis et metus lobortis faucibus quis eu eros. Nulla a augue dolor. Vestibulum sit amet leo sagittis, interdum mi eget, aliquam sem. Morbi elementum, tellus eu molestie sagittis, diam ipsum euismod nulla, at aliquet sapien tellus non nisi. Donec malesuada tellus lorem, vitae ullamcorper massa sagittis et. Praesent sodales tincidunt eros, eget tempor enim blandit vitae.</p>
<p>Aliquam gravida sagittis imperdiet. Fusce pellentesque metus vitae velit pharetra, eu tempus risus tempus. Maecenas egestas, turpis id euismod tristique, eros dui tempor elit, eu vulputate ipsum eros quis nibh. Nulla facilisi. Aliquam eget dui condimentum, tempor sapien in, dapibus magna. Nam nec velit mauris. Nunc auctor, eros quis bibendum lacinia, elit diam ornare nulla, ut viverra arcu nibh in odio. Quisque nibh ipsum, dictum ullamcorper purus in, condimentum fermentum risus. Nullam eget mollis magna. Phasellus rhoncus dignissim blandit. Sed massa ex, mollis id placerat in, convallis in velit. Sed molestie volutpat justo sit amet eleifend.</p>
<p>Ut dui est, mollis eget efficitur quis, dapibus et quam. Sed est erat, pulvinar et efficitur et, blandit sit amet purus. Nunc congue vitae enim id interdum. In euismod, felis at faucibus euismod, nunc nulla varius nisl, ut viverra nisl lectus a ipsum. Nunc sollicitudin felis eget viverra accumsan. Mauris id sem elit. Praesent ultrices lorem quis est malesuada, congue imperdiet mi sodales. Curabitur laoreet velit nisl, eget viverra ex posuere ac. Nullam pretium est ac semper fringilla. Integer sed egestas elit. Sed eu pharetra felis. Morbi eget enim sit amet tellus rutrum tincidunt. Nullam in efficitur magna. Suspendisse lobortis nisi at lectus blandit, vitae ullamcorper urna placerat. Proin consequat, risus ut condimentum tristique, ex nibh vehicula dolor, non viverra eros odio eu augue.</p>
<p>Donec lectus sem, feugiat sed augue ac, dapibus bibendum leo. Donec pharetra vehicula fermentum. Donec ac urna lacus. Maecenas felis elit, laoreet ut vulputate ut, pretium in nisi. Integer elementum at enim eu pellentesque. Nunc in ornare erat. Donec sed hendrerit massa. Nunc mattis nunc at ex cursus, vel sodales turpis pulvinar.</p>
<p>Suspendisse euismod condimentum scelerisque. Donec finibus justo at erat molestie, venenatis lobortis justo blandit. Fusce id arcu maximus, scelerisque dui eu, blandit dui. Morbi rhoncus pharetra porta. Duis rhoncus dui nec odio rhoncus mollis. Aenean et metus turpis. Duis ut metus mi. Nam eleifend sapien et nisl vehicula iaculis. Praesent tortor tellus, pulvinar at ipsum ac, euismod porta felis. Nullam iaculis, ante vel pulvinar lobortis, mauris eros auctor nisl, consectetur maximus turpis lectus at odio.</p>
<p>Cras sed ex eget nibh fermentum molestie. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. In ac sollicitudin risus, id auctor elit. Fusce lacus orci, mattis ac neque non, malesuada feugiat mi. Morbi vel fringilla odio. In et nisi feugiat, varius ipsum nec, scelerisque massa. Etiam tincidunt rutrum sagittis. Fusce fringilla tincidunt vehicula. Pellentesque nec sem sed dui ultricies scelerisque. In pulvinar lacus sed eros cursus, imperdiet blandit neque fringilla. Nulla tempor molestie mattis. Donec et faucibus nibh. Duis nec turpis felis. Cras tempus eros quis nisi malesuada, non auctor neque porta.</p>
<p>Nullam est sapien, gravida finibus metus in, feugiat viverra nunc. Aenean at ultrices velit. Aenean tellus sapien, convallis eget metus at, elementum aliquet nunc. Vestibulum vestibulum risus quis arcu malesuada, eu feugiat velit elementum. Cras gravida ut massa ac aliquam. Fusce ornare luctus massa nec vestibulum. Sed vitae blandit ante. Nullam sed metus malesuada, bibendum sem sit amet, ullamcorper justo.</p>
<p>Ut sagittis semper molestie. Suspendisse potenti. Quisque eu commodo nisl. Praesent bibendum fermentum erat, vel mattis lacus aliquam eget. Morbi a laoreet risus, a tincidunt lectus. Integer elementum, justo nec commodo tempor, eros libero pretium diam, id feugiat magna risus at neque. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Integer non dapibus velit. Maecenas fringilla dolor quis rutrum bibendum. Nam tincidunt hendrerit ullamcorper. Praesent tempus lacus et dui consequat dignissim. Vivamus sit amet scelerisque nulla.</p>
<p>Cras et ipsum ut lorem pellentesque vulputate. Vestibulum molestie, lectus pulvinar suscipit suscipit, sem turpis dignissim magna, et ornare mauris purus bibendum metus. Phasellus in scelerisque augue. Vestibulum iaculis non dui sit amet lobortis. Nunc semper massa sed risus placerat, at ultrices libero varius. Nulla metus nunc, vestibulum at vulputate a, ultrices vitae dui. Praesent luctus consectetur felis, eget lobortis purus tristique vel. Donec tincidunt felis eget augue tincidunt dapibus.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think that your help is the best I'm likely to receive. Thank you for helping me find a solution. 
If you edit your answer to mention that it appears 'break-inside:avoid' and grid don't work together before presenting the alternative I'll accept it as the answer.
Currently it doesn't technically 'Answer' my question, just provides an alternative.